# How use await keyword along with asyncstorage setitem for server response?

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I'm trying to use asyncstorage in my react native app.The problem is the server response I'm getting takes some delay so I want to wait for the response then I want to use that responseData.user_id to be saved in my app.I'm using nodejs as backend and mysql db.So after user registration I'm inserting it to db at the same time I've written another query for fetching their user_id (PK).So this responseData is getting to client and I'm trying to take that user_id from the response.So I've written something like this

```
   onPressRegister = async () => {

  try {
    let response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.2:3000/users/registration', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'applictaion/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',

      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        contact: this.state.contact,
        password: this.state.password,
      })
    });

    let responseData = await response.json();

    if (responseData) {

      try {
                Action.firstScreen();
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('userid', JSON.stringify(responseData.userData.phone_no));
      }
      catch (e) {
        console.log('caught error', e);
      }

    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }

}
```

And in my next screen I'm accessing the userid like this.And passing it the next API call like this.

```
         getUserId = async () => {
      let userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userid');
      return userId;
    }


onPressYes = (workType) => {
        this.getUserId().then((userId) => {

   this.setState({userId:userId})
```

})

```
         fetch('http://192.168.1.2:3000/users/user_request',{
           method:'POST',
           headers:{
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           },
           body:  JSON.stringify({
            workType,
            phone:this.state.userId
             })
         })
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then((responseData) => {
           this.setState({
           data:responseData
         });
         });
     }
```

But this is the error I'm getting. [image: error]

Comment: you correctly `await AsyncStorage.setItem` ... so why don't you `let usid = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userid');` where it's probably more important that you wait for the value

Comment: If you don't add the `try`, you can see what is your problem.

Comment: ` data: 'User registered Successfully',
  userData:
   { pwd: 'mkmk',
     phone_no: '23',
     user_name: '',
     status: 1,
     date: 2018-10-25T05:31:12.358Z },
  user_id: 16,
  token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.}` This is how responseData looks like , the thing is I'm able to set the token within asyncstorage but not user_id..strange., please have a look https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI1A6.png

Comment: AFAIK `AsyncStorage` stores string values only. So you should try something like `JSON.stringify(responseData.user_id)` in your `setItem` call.

Comment: Your original code appears to have  a random line declaring the function `async getCache(userid){...}` in it.
That's what's causing the error in your output. Why are you declaring a function in the middle of processing code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
onPressRegister = async () => {

  try {
    let response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.6:3000/users/registration', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'applictaion/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',

      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        contact: this.state.contact,
        password: this.state.password,
      })
    });

    let responseData = await response.json();

    if (responseData) {

      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('userid', JSON.stringify(responseData.user_id));
      }
      catch (e) {
        console.log('caught error', e);
      }

    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }

}
```

To access the value in some other component:

```
getUserId = async () => {
  let userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userid');
  return userId;
}

componentWillMount() {
  this.getUserId().then((userId) => {
    console.log(userId);
  })
}
```

Comment: Can I save the values within state?How do I do that? I want this `userd_id` to be passed to another API call.So please help..I've tried your code but navigation to next screen is not working.Please help

Comment: State variables are volatile and their value will be lost if the component unmounts. To permanently persist some data you'll need `AsyncStorage`. You can definitely pass `userid` to some API once it has correctly been retrieved from storage. Navigating to other screen is a separate issue, first you should confirm if `userid` is being stored and retrieved correctly in the same component. First store it and then fetch its value to see what happens.

Comment: I've edited my code according to your's. But the problem is where do I set the navigation in register screen.I'm using react-native-router-flux.Please help..

Comment: I'm afraid I am not very well-versed with `react-native-router-flux` as I have used `react-navigation` only. You should look at its documentation or open a separate question since that is a completely different issue.

Comment: Yes, I've posted question before about the same issue but I can't find any response.So that's why.Please help.

Comment: [This article](https://blog.theodo.fr/2017/03/how-to-create-an-authentication-system-and-a-persistent-user-session-with-react-native/) is the closest thing I could find according to your predicament. Please go through it in detail, I am sure it will help.